# How to commit changes to Git as another user?

Tags: git, macos, permissions, bitbucket

I need to setup new user account to access our two repos on BitBucket. New user has a read access to one repo and write access to the second repo.

I know how to setup permission via BitBucket administration webpage but I would like to test in in real environment - clone repo and try to commit changes back.

**My question** - how to clone (OSX box) a BitBucket repo as new user (other than me) and try to commit changes back to the repo as this user to test user permissions setup?

Answer (score 0):

You have a section in the `.git/config` file in your local repository like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = REMOTEURL
```

Most probably the remote url contains your user name. You can temporarily change the username here. This is for pushing.

If you want to change the commit user one very easy solution is this:

`git config user.name NEWUSERNAME`

Issue this command in your local clone.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to test from command line.

Clone repository using http protocol and type you first user login+password. Make changes and simply pass second user credentials when you asked.

If you ssh-key authentication things a bit more complicated.
SSH key located in `/.ssh/` directory and named something like `id_rsa` or `id_dsa` (the matter of cryptographic algorithm). Probably I'd generate two new ssh keys, associate one with user-a and second with user-b on BitBucket and put a proper key to `/.ssh` directory.